# Angular : how to use constant in a module

Tags: angularjs

I'm a new in AngularJS and I would like to understand how to use constant in a module.

Here the code I use :

**users-management.module.js**

```
    angular
        .module('app.users-management', [])
        .config(config);

    /** @ngInject */
    function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider, msApiProvider, msNavigationServiceProvider)
    {
      console.log(USER_ROLES); // doesn't work
      ...
    }
```

**my run block** :

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('fuse')
        .run(runBlock);

    /** @ngInject */
    function runBlock($rootScope, $timeout, $state, $cookieStore, USER_ROLES, authService)
    {
        console.log(USER_ROLES); // OK
       ...
    }
 }
```

**and here my config file** :

```
(function ()
{
   'use strict';

   var cfg = {
        base_url : '127.0.0.1/'
   };

   var userRoles = {
        all: '*',
        admin: 'admin',
        editor: 'editor'     
   };

   angular
       .module('fuse')
       .constant('CONFIG_API', cfg)
       .constant('USER_ROLES', userRoles);
})();
```

How can I use USER_ROLES in my users-management module ?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found ! Thank very much Makoto and Mickael :)

Here what I changed :

```
   angular
       .module('fuse') // ONLY FUSE module...
       .constant('CONFIG_API', configApi)
       .constant('USER_ROLES', userRoles);

  angular
       .module('app.core') // all modules...
       .constant('CONFIG_API', configApi)
       .constant('USER_ROLES', userRoles);
```

Thank very much guys !

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use your constant from another module, and simply put, that module has no inclination as to where it came from.

You could mitigate this by adding the `fuse` module as a dependency.  Then, your constant will work as you expect it to.

```
angular.module('app.users-management', ['fuse'])
```

Comment: I added fuse as a dependency but how do I use USER_ROLES ? if I do something like that "console.log(USER_ROLES)", it's still not defined.

Comment: Are you injecting it?